# Laravel where issue on secondary join

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I have a blog and I'm wanting to display all categories with posts within  a dynamic change date start and date end.

I have the following eloquent query:

```
$Categories = Category::with('Posts')
                ->whereHas('Posts', function ($query) use ($StartDate, $EndDate) {
                    $query->where('created_at', '>=', $StartDate);
                    $query->where('created_at', '<=', $EndDate);
                })
                ->get();
```

This will return only return categories with `Posts` between the two dates.

I've found online to add `doesntHave`.

```
$Categories = Category::with('Posts')
            ->doesntHave('Posts')
            ->orWhereHas('Posts', function ($query) use ($StartDate, $EndDate) {
                $query->where('created_at', '>=', $StartDate);
                $query->where('created_at', '<=', $EndDate);
            })
            ->get();
```

This returns `Categories` that have no `posts` or `posts` within the date range. However, if there is a category that has `posts` but none of them are within the date range, they won't appear at all.

How can I show all `categories` and join the `posts` within the date range? If there are no posts within the range it should return as null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some tweaking..

```
$Categories = Category::with('Posts', function ($query) use ($StartDate, $EndDate) {
                        $query->whereBetween('created_at', [$StartDate, $EndDate]);
                    })
                    ->get();
```